# QTP Test cases fail sometimes and pass sometimes. Individually they pass

Tags: qtp

When I run my test cases individually they run ok and pass. But when I run a test suite, some of the test cases fail and when I re-run the test suite, the same test cases pass but fails another set of test cases.

So I introduced wait cycles between all the test cases. I have 1000's of test cases and I kept doing that for each and individual test cases. in between code, after each test script(case)... but I want to know how to deal with such fails when there are 1000's of test cases.  I don't know if I am doing it right. Please help me.

Comment: I have faced this same issue sometime back with Telerik's Test Studio, but with the use of Wait commands, correct grouping of test cases and increasing the default timeout value, mine issue got resolved. See if you can group your test cases and slow down the execution process, then it may help you too (although you have already used the wait in your cases).

Answer (score 1):

Putting in arbitrary sleep times is usually a very bad idea when it comes to test automation. Instead of putting in sleeps between test steps (or test cases), it is far better to put in checking mechanisms to ensure that the system under test is ready for the next test step (or test case).

Here's a generic example:

```
Do Step A
sleep 10 seconds
Do Step B
```

The above *may* pass *now* but will break very easily, and also potentially waste much time. What if sometimes your system becomes ready after 0.5 seconds? You are needlessly spending 9.5 seconds without performing any meaningful task.

The fact that you had to sleep for 10 seconds tells you that whatever you did in Step A puts the system under test in a state such that it takes time for it to become ready for step B.  So figure out the conditions that need to be met for the system to become ready for step B, then check that those conditions are met. (This could be turned into another test assertion in itself, and often, is a good idea to do exactly that.)

Thus a much better way of progressing is follows:

```
Do Step A
Wait for the system to become ready for Step B
Do Step B
```

Implementing the waiting step usually involves a loop and a time out, such as:

```
initTime = getCurrentTime()
goodToGo = False
while (getCurrentTime() - initTime) < timeOut:
    if condition to perform step B is met:
        goodToGo = True
        break
    sleep(checkInterval)
if goodToGo:
    PASSED - We can proceed to step B
else:
    FAILED - Something is wrong
```

Similar code blocks to the above occur regularly in our automation testing code base. The value for `timeOut` should be high enough such that if `timeOut` is reached (i.e. `goodToGo == False` at the end of the loop) you know for sure that a failure condition has occurred, but low enough such that the whole test run isn't delayed too much when such a failure condition occurs. `checkInterval` should be set to a reasonable value so that we move onto step B quickly after the system becomes ready, but not put too much stress on the system by polling too often.

As a final note, intermittently passing test cases can often mean intermittent issues with the system being tested. What is the actual *root* cause? Why does putting in arbitrary sleeps in between test cases cause your test cases to pass?

As a tester, I would be extremely curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

Tests that sometimes fail are usually an indication that the tests used can't handle the inherent instability of your system.
You would either need to make the tests react to changes in the system, or you'd need to introduce wait times that would make the test more failsafe.
You could also loop certain parts of your test X times before they fail.

Either use a more stable testing environment or adapt your tests to the environment.